# Select using concat in single table by joining parent & child id's

Tags: join, psql

I have one table with 3 columns are below

```
+---------------------------------------+
| id  | name                | parent_id |
+---------------------------------------+
| -1  | /                   |           |
| 1   | Organization        | -1        |
| 2   | United States       |  1        |
| 3   | Business Analyst    |  1        |
| 4   | Human Resources     |  1        |
| 5   | Benefits Manager    |  4        |
| 6   | Metropolitan Plant  |  2        |
| 7   | Administration      |  6        |
+---------------------------------------+
```

And my query is like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(parent.name, '/', child.name) AS path 
 FROM table_name AS child INNER JOIN table_name AS parent 
 ON child.id = parent.parent_id
```

I am expecting output as below.

```
/Organization
/Organization/United States
/Organization/Business Analyst
/Organization/Human Resources
/Organization/Human Resources/Benefits Manager
/Organization/United States/Metropolitan Plant
/Organization/United States/Metropolitan Plant/Administration
```

Comment: Please tag properly.  This is MySQL or Posgres??  You put tag for both.  Can't be both.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...there might be a more elegant way to do this...especially with using do loops...but with what immediately comes to mind, you may need to do several joins. Is the maximum level low? I hope so. Here's an idea, but it's messy and may require a lot of spool depending on your data size:

```
SELECT CONCAT(path2, '/', D.name) AS path3
FROM
(SELECT CONCAT(path1, '/', B.name) AS path2
FROM
(SELECT CONCAT(parent.name, '/', child.name) AS path1 
FROM table_name AS parent LEFT JOIN table_name AS child
ON child.id = parent.parent_id) AS A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_NAME AS B
ON A.id = B.parent_id) AS C
LEFT JOIN TABLE_NAME AS D
ON C.id = D.parent_id
```

The above code would only take it up to 3 levels. If something better comes to mind, I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

Suspect you're expected to use a hierarchical query here

```
WITH foo (id, parent_id, name, fullpath)
     AS (SELECT id,
                parent_id,
                name,
                '/' AS fullpath
           FROM table_name
          WHERE parent_id IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT m.id,
                m.parent_id,
                m.name,
                f.fullpath || m.name || '/' AS fullpath
           FROM foo f JOIN table_name m ON (m.parent_id = f.id)) 
SELECT fullpath  FROM foo  
WHERE id > 0
```

That'll be pretty close.